# Transparent layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have something like that inside my RelativeLayout:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/picture"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@drawable/pic"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:background="@color/black"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_margin="50dp"
                   android:background="@color/transparent"
                   android:id="@+id/ivSelection"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want LinearLayout to be black and ivSelection to be transparent; and through ivSelection I want to see ivPicture's image. Margins of ivSelection is changeable and, of course, this "window" must be changeable (resizeable) too.
Something like that: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/8382/selm.jpg

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:background="@color/black" 
                   android:src="@drawable/pic"
                   android:padding="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/ivSelection"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: create one more ImageView and set color of resizeble ivSelection to transparent:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/picture"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@drawable/pic"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/drawSelection"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@color/transparent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_margin="50dp"
                   android:background="@color/transparent"
                   android:id="@+id/ivSelection"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When changing ivSelection's margin, we need to do something like:

```java
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(R.color.black);
c.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, p);

Xfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
p.setXfermode(mode);
p.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
c.drawRect(sel.leftMargin,
           sel.topMargin,
           w - sel.rightMargin,
           h - sel.bottomMargin, p);

drawSelection.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```